# Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe"

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a problem with apache restart

We are using the CWPPro admin panel for multiple domains are hosted in CWPPro. Apache is not working. Showing Fail status. After restarting, the following is the error message:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After getting log file following are errors:

```
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb systemd[1]: Starting Web server Apache...
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb apachectl[27117]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/afridian/public_html] does not exist
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb apachectl[27117]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/afridian/public_html] does not exist
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb apachectl[27117]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/thebriti/public_html] does not exist
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb apachectl[27117]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/thebriti/public_html] does not exist
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb systemd[1]: Failed to start Web server Apache.
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Aug 09 06:18:39 bweb systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

[image]

Comment: `Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/thebriti/public_html] does not exist.` The error seems obvious.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon, or by adding a line containing three backticks before AND after the text.   (BTW, your image with unreadable light-grey text on a yellow background and white text on orange buttons is even worse than most images of text. it's not only unreadable, it's a hideous eyesore)